# Why does the error "is not constrained by the impl trait" occur when only changing the definition of the offending type parameter?

Tags: rust

This question builds on [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76762790/3096687), which may be useful to see for context.

Here is the original trait in question, along with the simplest implementation (i.e. for `T: Fn() -> TR`):

```rust
pub trait Ext<T> {
    type Output;
    fn call_with_tuple(self, x: T) -> Self::Output;
    fn to_tuple_fn(self) -> Box<dyn Fn(T) -> Self::Output>;
}

impl<T: 'static, TR> Ext<()> for T
where
    T: Fn() -> TR,
{
    type Output = TR;
    fn call_with_tuple(self, _: ()) -> Self::Output {
        self()
    }
    fn to_tuple_fn(self) -> Box<dyn Fn(()) -> Self::Output> {
        Box::new(move |_| self())
    }
}
```

To get around the issue where some type information is lost after a value is returned from a generic function (in particular `to_tuple_fn` will not preserve any traits of the original value, such as `Clone`), we can try to change `T: Fn() -> TR` to be `T: CloneableFn<(), TR>`. This results in [the error](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/error_codes/E0207.html):

```
error[E0207]: the type parameter `TR` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
  --> src/main.rs:52:18
   |
52 | impl<T: 'static, TR> Ext<()> for T
   |                  ^^ unconstrained type parameter
```

But I don't see why this is the case, as only the definition of `TR` change, not how it appears in the rest of the trait impl.

Here's a [playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=23f7650ce02a37e0c8a118d9b3e3bf8e) demonstrating the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax `Fn() -> TR` is desugared into the trait bound `Fn<(), Output = TR>`. [`Output`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnOnce.html#associatedtype.Output) is an associated type. Associated types constrain generic parameters, so this is fine.

But with your trait, this is not an associated type anymore but a type parameter. They don't constrain generic parameters, so this fails.

Change it to be an associated type and it will work.

Comment: When trying to do this, it seemed I still needed a type parameter in order to specify the associated type, which got us back to the original issue. Instead, I tried using generic associated types (GATs), with which I'm admittedly not terribly familiar. However, I seem to [run into object safety issues there](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8a02b25821a17fcf2000c9995ad950e8).

Comment: Actually, the GATs may have been a bad lead; removing them seems to get me closer but I'm currently taking a look to understand why `Clone` [isn't being picked up at the use-site](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8a68ae5fdde2d3c78fa221f00cf280b6).

Comment: Some improvements I think, but it seems `foo` is [no longer recognized](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e1f4562c4f089a96017ce2ad6368d47c) as a `CloneableFn`.