# How to avoid conflicting implementation issue in a Rust macro involving invocations for different arities?

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I have the following trait, and would like it to work for any `Fn`.

```rust
pub trait CloneableFn<Args, O>: Fn(Args) -> O {
    fn clone_box<'a>(&self) -> Box<dyn 'a + CloneableFn<Args, O>>
    where
        Self: 'a;
}
```

After trying [various approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76779849/3096687), I'm now trying to use a macro.

```rust
macro_rules! cloneable_fn {
    ($($arg:ident),* $ (,)?) => {
        impl<$($arg,)* O, FN: Fn(($($arg),*)) -> O + Clone> CloneableFn<($($arg),*) , O> for FN
        {
            fn clone_box<'a>(&self) -> Box<dyn 'a + CloneableFn<($($arg),*), O>>
            where
                Self: 'a,
            {
                Box::new(self.clone())
            }
        }
    };
}

cloneable_fn!();
// cloneable_fn!(A);
cloneable_fn!(A, B);
cloneable_fn!(A, B, C);
cloneable_fn!(A, B, C, D);
cloneable_fn!(A, B, C, D, E);
cloneable_fn!(A, B, C, D, E, F);
cloneable_fn!(A, B, C, D, E, F, G);
```

This appears to compile, but if I uncomment the line `cloneable_fn!(A);`, there is an error:

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `util::CloneableFn<(), _>`
  --> src/util.rs:52:9
   |
52 |         impl<$($arg,)* O, FN: Fn(($($arg),*)) -> O + Clone> CloneableFn<($($arg),*) , O> for FN
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |         |
   |         first implementation here
   |         conflicting implementation
...
65 | cloneable_fn!(A);
   | ---------------- in this macro invocation
   |
   = note: this error originates in the macro `cloneable_fn` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

At first, I thought it had to do with a parentheses issue, but the issue remained I left `cloneable_fn!(A);` commented and manually added an impl:

```rust
impl<A, B, F: Fn(A) -> B + Clone> CloneableFn<A, B> for F {
    fn clone_box<'a>(&self) -> Box<dyn 'a + CloneableFn<A, B>>
    where
        Self: 'a,
    {
        Box::new(self.clone())
    }
}
```

Is there a solution to this approach that would work with any arity (it's fine if the solution involves some special case implementations)?

Comment: I think you can just replace all `$($arg),*` with `$($arg,)*` to make even the 1-tuple a tuple instead of a plain value in parentheses, if that's what you want I don't know though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue boils down to a syntax quirk: `(A)` is not interpreted as a 1-ary tuple of a generic type `A`, but as *just* `A`, and thus the implementation for `ClonableFn<A, O>` conflicts with every other `ClonableFn` implementation, as `()`, `(A, B)`, ... are types.

This is also why your manual implementation fails: you attempt to write `ClonableFn<A, O>` which just conflicts with the world.

The implementation you want -- for unary tuple -- needs to be written for `CloneableFn<(A,), O>`.

You could, of course, write it manually... but it can indeed be achieved by "fixing" your macro: depending on whether the comma is placed inside or outside the parentheses, `$()*` (and `$()+`) behave differently:

- Inside: present after each element<sup>1</sup>.
- Outside: present after each element *but* the last.

Using the Playground, and clicking on "Tools > Expand Macros" we can see the difference in action.

Your version (outside):

```rust
#[allow(unused_parens)]
impl<O, FN: Fn(()) -> O + Clone> CloneableFn<(), O> for FN {
    fn clone_box<'a>(&self) -> Box<dyn 'a + CloneableFn<(), O>> where
        Self: 'a {
        Box::new(self.clone())
    }
}
#[allow(unused_parens)]
impl<A, O, FN: Fn((A)) -> O + Clone> CloneableFn<(A), O> for FN {
    fn clone_box<'a>(&self) -> Box<dyn 'a + CloneableFn<(A), O>> where
        Self: 'a {
        Box::new(self.clone())
    }
}
#[allow(unused_parens)]
impl<A, B, O, FN: Fn((A, B)) -> O + Clone> CloneableFn<(A, B), O> for FN {
    fn clone_box<'a>(&self) -> Box<dyn 'a + CloneableFn<(A, B), O>> where
        Self: 'a {
        Box::new(self.clone())
    }
}
```

[Fixed version](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=72c6be1401ffa8954732ea409f2afac4) (inside):

```rust
#[allow(unused_parens)]
impl<O, FN: Fn(()) -> O + Clone> CloneableFn<(), O> for FN {
    fn clone_box<'a>(&self) -> Box<dyn 'a + CloneableFn<(), O>> where
        Self: 'a {
        Box::new(self.clone())
    }
}
#[allow(unused_parens)]
impl<A, O, FN: Fn((A,)) -> O + Clone> CloneableFn<(A,), O> for FN {
    fn clone_box<'a>(&self) -> Box<dyn 'a + CloneableFn<(A,), O>> where
        Self: 'a {
        Box::new(self.clone())
    }
}
#[allow(unused_parens)]
impl<A, B, O, FN: Fn((A, B)) -> O + Clone> CloneableFn<(A, B), O> for FN {
    fn clone_box<'a>(&self) -> Box<dyn 'a + CloneableFn<(A, B), O>> where
        Self: 'a {
        Box::new(self.clone())
    }
}
```

The trailing comma in `(A,)` makes all the difference.

<sup>1</sup> *Wait, you say, there's no trailing comma in `(A, B)`! You are correct, and I am puzzled. Strictly speaking it's unnecessary, but even `cargo expand --ugly` lacks it, even though it should be strictly expanded code, with no reformatting. I'll update this answer once I understand why.*

Comment: I wonder if removing the "," for non-unary tuples happens in an early phase of the compiler (I know nothing about the internals of the Rust compiler). Thanks for the wonderful answer!